# Links not working in Framework7

Tags: php, html, mobile, html-framework-7

I'm developing a web-based application using **Framework7** (http://www.idangero.us/framework7/).

I'm doing well but now that I have come to integrate my **login/member** system I have encountered a problem with hyperlinks.

I've spent couple of hours trying to figure it out but have still come up short.

Basically I have three links:

```
<div class="pages navbar-through toolbar-through">
    <div data-page="index" class="page">

        <div class="page-content">

            <div class="content-block">
                <div class="content-block-inner">
                    Hello <?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>, secret content!<br />
                    <a href="memberlist.php">Memberlist</a><br />
                    <a href="edit_account.php">Edit Account</a><br />
                    <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

`Memberlist.php` and `edit_account.php` do not work but logout does.

Visiting the files directly in my browser (eg domain.com/memberlist.php) loads the file. They just do not load from this page so something is clearly wrong with it.

I've tried to include `target="_self"` and use other styles of linking content as explained in the Framework7 documentation but there is nothing about the problem I'm experiencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it important to write exact page name in data-page attribute value

```
<div class="page" data-page="about">
```

Answer (score 0):

After digging around some more in the documentation I was able to solve my issue.

Linking in Framework7 requires every page linked to to have some specific code for parsing over AJAX.

```
 <!-- That is all we have in about.html file -->
<div class="page" data-page="about">
  ... About page content goes here
</div>
```